# What is the difference between "dnf history rollback" and "dnf history undo"?

Tags: fedora, rhel, package-management, dnf

Let's read the [official documentation](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#history-command-label):

> `dnf history rollback <transaction-spec>`
>   Undo all transactions performed after the specified transaction. If it is not possible to **undo** any transaction due to the current state of RPMDB, do not undo any transaction.

Emphasis is mine. So this command refers to the `undo` command. Okay, let's read the documentation concerning undo:

> `dnf history undo <transaction-spec>`
>   Perform the opposite operation to all operations performed in the specified transaction. If it is not possible to undo any operation due to the current state of RPMDB, do not undo any operation.

It sounds that those two commands do the same things with the exception that the former can undo several transactions, and the later just one.

**Is this understanding correct?** (I would appreciate answers from first-hand experience, not from the point of view how *you interpret* the manual, I'm interested in facts, not guesses.)

Context: I need to write a script that runs `dnf upgrade -y` and then runs some tests and then *reverse the dnf changes* if the tests fail. I'm looking for the best way of achieving this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`undo` only undoes that specific transaction, while `rollback` undoes everything *between* that transaction and the current state of the system.

Example: you install `htop`, then later install `ncdu` and `glances`, followed by `mc` the next day.

You later want to undo installing htop, so you use the undo function to try to undo installing htop, but still keep the other programs you installed later.

If you rolled back to the transaction that installed `htop`, you'd instead undo  the installation of `ncdu`, `glances` and `mc`, while still keeping `htop`.

Comment: Yep, that I how I understood it too, but wanted to confirm, thank you for doing that! ;)